# save values from 2 or more UserControls in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am working in Fast Survey Project!!

i have no time for design a database and all these things ,i have only one table and i have to fill the answers , i have to finish it within two days.

the problem is I have more than 50 questions and i divided them into 3 groups , i putted  each question group in User Control, and i am trying to save the values from each user control.

i want to save theme temporarily after each user control and when the user reach  the last user control and click finish button it should save all the answers one time .

so is there any idea?? I was thinking to use something like global file !!

but i don't whether it works or not but i am working on it now and i hope to find any idea from you people.

Comment: Let me see if I understand: a) You have a database with a table containing questions. b) you want to display those questions - one at a time - using ASP.NET c) you want to accumulate the answers as each question is answered d) Finally, you would like to display the results to the user. What have you done so far?

Comment: well ,not exactly!!

the questions are static on the page and the answers also !!


and i don't want to show the user what did he answer.
and the table is only for saving  the results.

Comment: Static hard coded questions????

Comment: yes it's hard coded , i have to finish it As Soon As Possible .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can temporarily save in session:

```
var survey = new Survey();
Survey.Name = textBoxName.Text;
Session["answer"] = survey.
```

Then later in all forms you can use:

```
var survey = Session["answer"] as Survey;
if (survey == null)
   //error, redirect to start
```

Where Survey class is class, which contains all survey info.

---

Other example,

```
//Form1, question 1
List<string> survey = new List<string>();
survey.Add(textBox1.Text);
Session["survey"] = survey;

//Form2, question2
var survey = Session["survey"] as List<string>;
survey.Add(textBox1.Text);

//Form...n... final save
var survey = Session["survey"] as List<string>;
for(int i=0; i< survey.Count;i++)
{
    SaveAnswer("someId", i, survey(i));
}
```

Comment: i think using sessions in this case is not good,

because i have more than 50 questions ,in this case i need to make more than 50 session to save the answers !!

it can work but is int there any better solution ??

Comment: @HAJJAJ: I think you are confused here: The number of sessions has nothing to do with the number of questions. One user will have one session (wihtin a specific time frame) when interacting with your web site.

Comment: mmm.. no this not what i want exactly then .

let us say that we have three pages .. in each page there are 5 questions .
when the user start to answer the questions the system should save the answers in a variables in each page behind code ... and when he reach  the last page and click on the finish button it should save all the answers from those variables to the database !!!

Comment: In my answer I wanted to say: create one class (or maybe List<string> it's your choice) with all needed answers. Store it to session and fill it in series of forms. When you fill it, do with it everything you want: send by mail, save to database and etc.

Comment: "and when he reach the last page and click on the finish button it should save all the answers from those variables to the database" Is it really problem? If you don't tell computer what to do, how would it know?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution

1. Create a question page which accepts a querystring containing questionID
2. Save question responses on the session.
3. Implement a [next] and [previous] button on the question page that let's the user navigate to a url with a different questionID (first question is a special case that doesn't have [previous])
4. Create a result page
5. When there isn't any [next] question available, change button caption to [finish] and point to result page
6. For result page. Retrieve correct answers from your table and retrieve user answers from session. Compare and display result

If you want to display a page with a *group* of up to three question on each page, then it becomes slightly more complicated. The question page would then be referenced with the groupID instaed.

If you only have 2 days for your implementation, then I would certainly settle for the simple one-question-per-page solution.

Comment: questions and results are static and i need to save the answers only from on page to another temporary to save them in the last page .

Answer (score 0):

This is easily solvable through UserControl public properties.

Here is how i would solve this:

1. Each user control that display question will have two properties - Question and Answer.
2. On the Page Submit button handler i will include the following logic block

```
// this dictionary will eventually be serialized and kept in session 
// throughout the whole Q&A session
var questionsAndAnswers = new Dictionary();
foreach(var control in MyUserControls) 
{
    questionsAndAnswers.Add(control.Question, control.Answer);
}
this.Session["q&a"] = questionsAndAnswers;
```

Something like that should do the work.

The main point here is the emphasis on getting the needed information through exposed properties from your child controls (the same concept can be applied on any parent/child level in your code).